# switching javascript image source path

Tags: javascript, image, imagesource

i downloaded a theme in my website, Now i want to edit the javascript image source of the path of my image. My index.html is located at my root directory and my other .html files are located in main.

My problem is, when i go to another page, i need this image path to show my image:

```
<img src="../assets/corporate/img/up.png" style="width:40px; height:40px" />
```

Now when i am at the index.html, i need another path to be use like this:

```
<img src="assets/corporate/img/up.png" style="width:40px; height:40px" />
```

i tried using this :

```
<img src="/assets/corporate/img/up.png" style="width:40px; height:40px" />
```

how can i switch with these two with these codes from the template i downloaded ?

Here is the whole code of the javascript template:

```
var scrolltotop={
    //startline: Integer. Number of pixels from top of doc scrollbar is scrolled before showing control
    //scrollto: Keyword (Integer, or "Scroll_to_Element_ID"). How far to scroll document up when control is clicked on (0=top).
    setting: {startline:100, scrollto: 0, scrollduration:1000, fadeduration:[500, 100]},
    controlHTML: '<img src="/assets/corporate/img/up.png" style="width:40px; height:40px" />', //HTML for control, which is auto wrapped in DIV w/ ID="topcontrol"
    controlattrs: {offsetx:10, offsety:10}, //offset of control relative to right/ bottom of window corner
    anchorkeyword: '#top', //Enter href value of HTML anchors on the page that should also act as "Scroll Up" links

    state: {isvisible:false, shouldvisible:false},

    scrollup:function(){
        if (!this.cssfixedsupport) //if control is positioned using JavaScript
            this.$control.css({opacity:0}) //hide control immediately after clicking it
        var dest=isNaN(this.setting.scrollto)? this.setting.scrollto : parseInt(this.setting.scrollto)
        if (typeof dest=="string" && jQuery('#'+dest).length==1) //check element set by string exists
            dest=jQuery('#'+dest).offset().top
        else
            dest=0
        this.$body.animate({scrollTop: dest}, this.setting.scrollduration);
    },

    keepfixed:function(){
        var $window=jQuery(window)
        var controlx=$window.scrollLeft() + $window.width() - this.$control.width() - this.controlattrs.offsetx
        var controly=$window.scrollTop() + $window.height() - this.$control.height() - this.controlattrs.offsety
        this.$control.css({left:controlx+'px', top:controly+'px'})
    },

    togglecontrol:function(){
        var scrolltop=jQuery(window).scrollTop()
        if (!this.cssfixedsupport)
            this.keepfixed()
        this.state.shouldvisible=(scrolltop>=this.setting.startline)? true : false
        if (this.state.shouldvisible && !this.state.isvisible){
            this.$control.stop().animate({opacity:1}, this.setting.fadeduration[0])
            this.state.isvisible=true
        }
        else if (this.state.shouldvisible==false && this.state.isvisible){
            this.$control.stop().animate({opacity:0}, this.setting.fadeduration[1])
            this.state.isvisible=false
        }
    },

    init:function(){
        jQuery(document).ready(function($){
            var mainobj=scrolltotop
            var iebrws=document.all
            mainobj.cssfixedsupport=!iebrws || iebrws && document.compatMode=="CSS1Compat" && window.XMLHttpRequest //not IE or IE7+ browsers in standards mode
            mainobj.$body=(window.opera)? (document.compatMode=="CSS1Compat"? $('html') : $('body')) : $('html,body')
            mainobj.$control=$('<div id="topcontrol">'+mainobj.controlHTML+'</div>')
                .css({position:mainobj.cssfixedsupport? 'fixed' : 'absolute', bottom:mainobj.controlattrs.offsety, right:mainobj.controlattrs.offsetx, opacity:0, cursor:'pointer'})
                .attr({title:'Scroll Back to Top'})
                .click(function(){mainobj.scrollup(); return false})
                .appendTo('body')
            if (document.all && !window.XMLHttpRequest && mainobj.$control.text()!='') //loose check for IE6 and below, plus whether control contains any text
                mainobj.$control.css({width:mainobj.$control.width()}) //IE6- seems to require an explicit width on a DIV containing text
            mainobj.togglecontrol()
            $('a[href="' + mainobj.anchorkeyword +'"]').click(function(){
                mainobj.scrollup()
                return false
            })
            $(window).bind('scroll resize', function(e){
                mainobj.togglecontrol()
            })
        })
    }
}

scrolltotop.init()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about having the image always show from the projects public root with `/` at the beginning:

`<img src="/assets/corporate/img/up.png" style="width:40px; height:40px" />`

Comment: <img src="/assets/corporate/img/up.png" style="width:40px; height:40px" />
i tried but it says image could not load

Comment: hello sir, can you help me? i tried that to always return to my root folder but the image also not showing